# Applying a space filtering

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a file containing 6 columns and I must plot 2 first columns but considering the points that have value in the 6th column. The 6th column has a lot of zero and almost zero number and when I put **a[5]>=0** it takes also some points that are almost zero, on the other hand, it is not possible to put a float filtering, I mean applying a filter on float array. How to apply a list for filtering the column to extract the buffer zone and the plotting the X and Y.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statistics 
from statistics import mode 
%matplotlib qt

def most_frequent(List): 
    counter = 0
    num = List[0] 
    for i in List: 
        curr_frequency = List.count(i) 
        if(curr_frequency> counter): 
            counter = curr_frequency 
            num = i 

    return num


with open('file_1001.out', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    near = [float(line.split()[5]) for line in lines]

    #list(filter(lambda  near: near = 0, lines))
    x = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in lines]
    y = [float(line.split()[1]) for line in lines]
print(most_frequent(near))

plt.plot(x[near<=0.0], y[near<=0.0], lw=1.75,label='Points filtered by 6th column= 0')
plt.plot(x,y,label='Plot without filter')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Provide a complete code with all variables defined. Where did `a` come from suddenly in your plot commands? Where did x and y go?

Comment: @Sheldore you're right. I forgot to fix the notation. now it's my true notation.

Comment: What is the buffer zone? Precise ranges can help you define the filters. `almost` is beyond computer intelligence.

Comment: @Sameeresque I meant a range between `0.0003-0.001`

Comment: "it is not possible to put a float filtering,". What does that mean? Numpy is great at it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist you're right. What I was trying to say, was your comment. Do you have any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). Here's an example that might be of help.

```
#cast your list as a numpy array   
a=np.asarray([0.1,0.01,0.02,0.0003,0.05,0.0009,0.0005],dtype=np.float32)
```

## To get the indices that satisfy your desired range:

```
np.where((a<0.001) & (a>0.0003))[0]
```

## To get the values corresponding to those indices:

```
a[np.where((a<0.001) & (a>0.0003))]
```

Comment: Actually the solution is smart but the problem is that `><` does not work for float numbers and I got this error `not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'`

Comment: You have to ensure that your list is cast as a NumPy array.

Comment: If your list is named as my_list, you can cast it as a NumPy array by setting: `np.asarray(my_list)`